# SQL Server : counter for insert,update,delete & select queries

Tags: sql-server-2008, counter, crud

I am a newbie to SQL Server. In MySQL to find the count of the insert, update, delete, select queries we have the below queries:

**SELECT**

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS like '%com_select%';
+-------------+-----+
| Variable_name | Value |
+-------------+-----+
| Com_select    | 1     |
+-------------+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**INSERT**

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS like '%com_insert%';
+-----------------+-----+
| Variable_name     | Value |
+-----------------+-----+
| Com_insert        | 0     |
| Com_insert_select | 0     |
+-----------------+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE**

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS like '%com_update%';
+----------------+-----+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+----------------+-----+
| Com_update       | 0     |
| Com_update_multi | 0     |
+----------------+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**DELETE**

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS like '%com_delete%';
+----------------+-----+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+----------------+-----+
| Com_delete       | 0     |
| Com_delete_multi | 0     |
+----------------+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Similarly are there any equivalent queries to find the count of the **insert**, **update**, **delete**, **select** queries in SQL Server?

Thanks !!!

**Edit** : A SQL server performance counter `sys.dm_os_performance_counters` provides the **Page reads/sec** & **writes/sec** like wise there anyother counters that can provide insert,update,delete counts?

Comment: If you enable CDC you can find this info: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid it seems available only for Enterprise, Developer, and Evaluation editions of SQL Server.But now i am using for a testing purpose.

Comment: In that case I don't think there are. So you want how many records inserted since _when_? `@@ROWCOUNT` gives you rows affected for the last operation.

Comment: Ok thanks @Nick.McDermaid.A MS SQL performance counter  `sys.dm_os_performance_counters` provides the count of read,writes per sec.Is there any similar couters for insert,update,delete.??

Comment: update/insert/delete since when? forever? last server restart? last 5 minutes? I'm not aware of anything that records that natively, If you go digging further into the dmv's you might find something. What is the purpose of this?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks! Since server restart.A testing purpose to find the current operations count in ms sql.

Comment: I had a quick look and I'm not aware of anything. There are any number of manual solutions generally around adding triggers to tables.